# post text with file to server via google's http client

Tags: android, upload, httpclient

I need post text with file to my sever on android device.I am using Google's HTTP Client with the MultipartContent to achieve it but unsuccess.
My code is below:

```
    MultipartContent multipart = new MultipartContent();
    multipart.addPart(new Part(new UrlEncodedContent(params)));

    if (null != mNeedUploadImages) {
        for (SelectedImage image : mNeedUploadImages) {
            multipart.addPart(new Part(new FileContent("image/jpeg", new File(image.imagepath))));
        }
    }

    HttpRequest request = getHttpRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(mUrl, multipart);
    request.execute();
```

Cause exception:

```
    java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
    at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.close(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:58)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:82)
    .....
```

I work for this for more than 1 day via Google and there doesn't appear to be much help. Any help would be great.Thanks.